# jquery ui resizable issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using `jquery-ui-1.9.2` and `jquery-ui dialog`, on mimimizing the dialogs they get into a container to the left side of the screen, i made the dialog container resizable by using the following code

```
$(function() {
    $( ".container" ).resizable();
});
```

and the css for it:

```
.container {
    position:fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    overflow: scroll
}
```

Now here clearly mentioned that container must show scrollbars only on overflow. This works fine if i take off the resizable function, but if i use that function then scrollbars appear on page load itself.

How do i get rid of this?

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i figured it out myself.
just changed the resizable() as shown below

```
$(function() {
$( ".container" ).resizable({ handles: "e" });
 });
```

Now the scrollbars appear only on overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `overflow: scroll` with `overflow: auto`

Comment: yes , i tried with all the overflow options and still the result is the same. i guess the resizable() is over-riding the css. is that possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But you can override overrided - include your CSS after jqueryui.css and specify your own css like `overflow: auto !important` to prevent other styles overrides yours.